# How to use poisson to estimate arrival time (generate random integers)?

Tags: python, random, poisson

In my assignment, I'm supposed to use a distribution curve to describe how many minutes will the employee come to work in advanced or later than the planed start time.

I decided to use Poisson distribution to solve my case. However, I don't know how should I assign the parameter to the Poisson function. I want my x-axis is from 0 to 60 minute (integer). The peak of the curve should be show up when x is 15. Should I just assign the lambda as 15?

I don't know if it's correct to use Poisson distribution to estimate the arrival time, and also don't know, if Poisson is correct, then should I just let the lambda be 15 and that's it, how can I set up a specific range (0, 60)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about computer programming. [statistics.se] or [mathematics.se] would be a better fit.

Comment: In addition to being off-topic, your question is under-specified. You haven't given any information which will allow for a plausible distribution to be given. Some people are never late but sometimes early. Some people are never early but sometimes late. Some people are fairly punctual (so the standard deviation will be fairly small). Others are much less reliable. Also, you seem to be confusing the Poisson and the closely related exponential distribution. The Poisson distribution itself is not a waiting time distribution.

Comment: I understand that some people will come earlier or later. If Poisson is anyway incorrect, I want to generate random integer between -30 and +30, and the distribuation curve should have its peak when x is -15.

Comment: Are you sure he'll definitely arrive between 30 minutes early and 30 minutes late? Most names distributions like this will be asymptotic in at least one direction, meaning there's still some probability that the employee will arrive, say, 200 minutes late, or not at all.

Comment: I'm not a statistic student. I just want to create a ideal case which can help me to generate the number I want. I know that someone arrives between 30 minutes early and 30 minutes late sounds not realistic, but it's what I need.

Comment: Why random *integer*? Time is measured on a continuous scale. Why not a normal distribution with mean 15? Again, you have given no information by which one distribution should be preferred to any other.

Comment: This random time integer is a very small part of my project. I need integer, because the data that I have is measured every 1 minute. I want to generate a random integer to shift my data. I checked a lot of distribuations, I found no one which fits my problem

Comment: That's because there isn't one natively. By "peak" do you mean mode or mean? They're not always the same thing, and likely won't be from the information you're giving. You can use a continuous distribution and round the result.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate this using the Poisson distribution with the following:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.poisson(15) - 30
if x > 30:
     x = 30
print(x)
```

This gives you a Poisson distributed value with mean of -15 that is no more than 30 minutes early. The if statement forces any values greater than +30 to be 30.

Comment: What is the negative for? I feel like this gets at what the poster wanted given the vague information.

Comment: I don't think that there is anything really wrong with your answer (given the vagueness of the question). Perhaps it was downvoted since the question itself is so off-topic that it shouldn't be answered. It would have made more sense for whoever downvoted you to downvote the question instead.

Comment: Two reasons for the downvote.  First, there's currently nothing in the question to indicate that the problem is with the syntax of generating or shifting a Poisson distribution. Second, while you might get away with it for P{Poisson(15) > 45} and a small sample size, as a general approach this is a bad way to try to bound the range because it creates a "bump" in the distribution at 30.  OP is equivocating about whether Poisson is appropriate, and if s/he tries to use this approach with other distributions it could significantly distort the tails of the distribution.

Comment: To me the OP seems to be indicating that there is a question about syntax in general, which would include shifting. And yes, they seem to be equivocating about using Poisson, but through conversation they made it clear that they're not as much interested in something "correct" statistically as they are in just producing something that gets a result—which this does.